# How to install ansible in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2

Tags: python, pip, ansible, yum

I am trying to install ansible in Azure VM

It was told " Ansible is not part of your RedHat DVD. It is a part of the python package. You need to install Ansible using the pip3 command "

After successfully installation with command `pip3 install ansible`

I don't see ansible command is not getting resolved. Could some guide me how to install ansible in right way?

```
[root@automation azureuser]# ansible
bash: ansible: command not found
```

Some diagnostic commands:

```
[root@automation site-packages]# echo $PATH 
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

[root@automation site-packages]# whereis ansible
ansible: /usr/local/bin/ansible

[root@automation site-packages]# which ansible
/usr/bin/which: no ansible in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

Comment: can you provide output of `echo $PATH`, `whereis ansible`, `which ansible` commands?

Comment: [root@automation site-packages]# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[root@automation site-packages]# whereis ansible
ansible: /usr/local/bin/ansible
[root@automation site-packages]# which ansible
/usr/bin/which: no ansible in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PATH` variable is `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` and that means that bash will search for `ansible` in these directories, however `ansible` placed in `/usr/local/bin`

You have to add `/usr/local/bin` to `$PATH`

How tos: [1](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-directory-to-path-in-linux/), [2](https://www.howtogeek.com/658904/how-to-add-a-directory-to-your-path-in-linux/), [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20add%20folder%20in%20path%20linux)

Also if you switch to non-root user `/usr/local/bin` should be present in `$PATH` by default (if I remember it correctly)

PS if you switched to `root` by using `sudo su`, use `sudo su -` instead. When you [adding `-`](https://superuser.com/questions/453988/whats-the-difference-between-su-with-and-without-hyphen#:%7E:text=The%20hyphen%20has%20two%20effects,as%20dictated%20by%20their%20%7E%2F.) some extra user specific variables will be imported (including extended `$PATH`)

Comment: It working after I do `sudo su -`  :) Thanks for attaching the difference between sudo su vs sudo su -

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow the official [documentation](https://Have%20you%20tried%20to%20follow%20the%20official%20%5Bdocumentation%5D%20(https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-rhel-centos-or-fedora)?)

You've to enable/install epel repository and install using:

```bash
sudo yum install ansible
```

Comment: I did try but no luck 
commands used 
EPEL repo installation 
`[root@automation ~]# yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm`

Ansible Installation 
`[root@automation ~]# sudo yum install ansible
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:11 ago on Fri 27 May 2022 09:38:39 AM UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides sshpass needed by ansible-2.9.27-3.el8.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)`

Comment: Your problem then is resolving dependencies for `sshpass` as it's needed for ansible.

Need to check your repositories and see which provides sshpass, RHEL it's subscription required so maybe need to check your subscription and/or enable repositories from there.

Comment: Able to do now with follow commands using EPEL packages. Thank You. 
`sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-$(rpm -E '%{rhel}').noarch.rpm` and `sudo yum -y install ansible`